# What do i set my STATIC_ROOT to when using django-storages, boto, boto3?

Tags: django, boto3, linode, object-storage, django-storage

I am using linode object storage and django project deployed on a linode server. I have everything set up as far as the linode bucket and aws settings in my settings.py but what do I set my static_root to?

```
STORAGES = {
  "default": {
    "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
    },
  "staticfiles": {
    "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage"
    },
  }
LINODE_BUCKET = "my_bucket"
LINODE_BUCKET_REGION = "us-east-1"
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = f"https://{LINODE_BUCKET_REGION}.linodeobjects.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had STATICFILES_DIR set, so it wanted a local path for STATIC_ROOT. I had to get rid of both of them for it to work